# Simplify lines with loop over numbers

Tags: python, loops, numbers, simplify

**Set-Up**

I assign specific columns from a pandas dataframe `radf` to a new dataframe `fdf` by the following lines,

```
fdf['avg rent pcm,<br> 1R'] = radf['avg rent pcm'][1]   
fdf['median rent pcm,<br> 1R'] = radf['median rent pcm'][1]  
fdf['# for rent,<br> 1R'] = radf['# for rent'][1]   

fdf['avg rent pcm,<br> 2R'] = radf['avg rent pcm'][2]  
fdf['median rent pcm,<br> 2R'] = radf['median rent pcm'][2]   
fdf['# for rent,<br> 2R'] = radf['# for rent'][2]
```

---

**Problem**

I'd like to simplify the above lines with a loop. In e.g. Stata this is quite straightforward. However, for Python I have never managed to make it work.

I've seen people do something like this,

```
for i in range(1,2):
     fdf['avg rent pcm,<br> {i}R'] = radf['avg rent pcm'][{i}]   
     fdf['median rent pcm,<br> {i}R'] = radf['median rent pcm'][{i}]  
     fdf['# for rent,<br> {i}R'] = radf['# for rent'][{i}]
```

but this does not work.

How to make this work?

Comment: why `[{i}]` instead of `[i]` and range is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` does not include the stop index and you should be formatting the string on the LHS:

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    fdf['avg rent pcm,<br> {i}R'.format(i=i)] = radf['avg rent pcm'][i]
```

On the RHS, you should not create a set from the index, but rather use it directly.

If on Python 3.6, you can use f-strings in-place of the more verbose `str.format`:

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    fdf[f'avg rent pcm,<br> {i}R'] = radf['avg rent pcm'][i]
    ...
```